# new instance of Object()

Tags: c#, .net

I came across this definition of `Object` constructor (metadata from `mscorlib.dll`)

```
[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
public Object();
```

I didn't understood what `ConstrainedExecution` (`Cer.MayFail`) mean can someone tell me with an example in this case.

I came across this code, also tell me if it is correct to write like this,

```
public class MyClass
{
    private static object instanceLock = new object();

    private void Func()
    {
        bool instanceLockTaken = false;

        Monitor.TryEnter(instanceLock, ref instanceLockTaken);
        //...
        Monitor.Exit(instanceLock);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but where exactly do you see "ConstrainedExecution" in the code you posted?

Comment: `CER` == `Constrained Execution Region`, mb?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I am afraid of `Cer.MayFail`, so what exactly might fail? object creation or something else.

Comment: You may choose to read this http://weblogs.asp.net/justin_rogers/archive/2004/10/05/238275.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constrained Execution is what you're trying to achieve by locking the thread.

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163716.aspx

> A Cer value of MayFail is used to signal that when faced with
>   asynchronous exceptions, the code may not complete in an expected
>   fashion. Since thread aborts are being delayed over constrained
>   execution regions, this really means that your code is doing something
>   that may cause memory to be allocated or that might result in a stack
>   overflow. More importantly, it means that you must take the possible
>   failures into consideration when calling this method.

In your case, because the object is static and only created once, this will not be a problem.

`Monitor.TryEnter` returns immediately even if a lock was not acquired. It has a boolean value, which you're not checking, something like this would work:

```
Monitor.TryEnter(instanceLock, ref instanceLockTaken);

  if (instanceLockTaken) 
  {
    // Do stuff here

    Monitor.Exit(instanceLock);
  }
```

However, this code would mean that the `if {}` block would not be executed every time, if you want to acquire a lock on every thread, you'll need to do something like this:

```
lock(instanceLock)
{
  // Do stuff here
}
```

This means that only a single thread can run the contents of the `lock {}` statement at a time, and the contents of the lock statement will be executed every time.

On a side note, you can also make the object you're locking `readonly`:

`private static readonly object instanceLock = new object();`

Comment: Also see undefined's answer re error handling. Very good point.

Answer (score 2):

So, generally speaking, you have 2 questions here.

1) Reliability contracts is a tool used by CLR team to support constrained execution regions. It is an advanced topic, but simply speaking the construction describes if a function (or a constructor) can fail, and if yes, what impact will be ( no impact, appDomain impact, process impact, whole machine crush, etc)

2) Your code snippet is incorrect. Why do you saving `instanceLockTaken` if you are not going to check it further? Furthermore, if exception  occur between the lock acquisition and releasing it, you'll leak the lock.
Consider using the `lock` statement, which is syntax sugar for something like this:

```
    bool instanceLockTaken = false;
    try
    {
      Monitor.Enter(instanceLock, ref instanceLockTaken);

    //...
    }
    finally
    {
      if (instanceLockTaken) 
      {
         Monitor.Exit(instanceLock);
      }
    }
```

Comment: In case of an un-handled exception in critical region, it would be wise to 'leak' the lock (and ultimately gracefully take down the current app-domain) than releasing some thread to work on corrupted shared state data...You should only release the lock if you can ensure that every thread will work on 'correct' state of the shared data (i.e. rollback to correct state in case of an exception)..ensuring correctness of shared state is the reason in first place that a lock is used...this is why 'lock' keyword is not a good candidate for critical region locking

Comment: `lock` statement is **not** a syntactic sugar for what you've written, i.e `try { Monitor.TryEnter(..) } finally { Monitor.Exit(..); }`, rather it is syntactic sugar for `try { Monitor.Enter(..) } finally { Monitor.Exit(..); }`. Notice the difference between `TryEnter()` and `Enter()`.

Answer (score 0):

Cer.Mayfail keyword implies that if the marked method throws an exception, the data may be in an invalid state; the previous state of the object will not be restored.

Comment: so you mean `new Object()` might fail and because that is not there in any try catch, my program might crash is that right?

Comment: no, let's say you have some operations in a method. And in the middle of the execution of this method, an exception is thrown; then changes applied to the objects in this method up to the point of exception will not be rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way for Monitor locking;

```
bool isLocked = false;
try
{
 Monitor.Enter(instanceLock , ref isLocked);
 // Do some things within the lock    
}
finally
{
 if (isLocked) Monitor.Exit(instanceLock);
}
```

As for cer.mayfail this link will provide some more information http://weblogs.asp.net/justin_rogers/archive/2004/10/05/238275.aspx